# Are there Flat-UI libraries for wxpython or just python?

Tags: python, wxpython

I've been searching for a library I can import and superimpose on my wxpython-based layout to give it a Flat-UI look.
Does there exist libraries that can be used along with wxpython or just python?

Comment: [`wx.lib`](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.lib-module.html) comes with a whole slew of owner-drawn widgets, some of which are flat (designed to look like the Safari bookmark bar). Some are called "FlatFoo", others "PlateFoo", some are in widget sets like AGW an some are on their own, and not all of them go together perfectly. And of course you have to change your code to use `wx.lib.PlateButton` instead of `wx.Button`, etc. Is that acceptable? Or are you looking for something that just re-styles all the default widgets all at once?

Comment: Also, note that `wx.lib` is mostly from a few years ago, when flat was something Apple applied sparingly to a few parts of their interfaces, rather than the new style of flat monochrome tiled squares, so I don't know if you'll be able to get that 1975 Xerox Alto look that everyone seems to love this week. But you can try it and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the custom widgets in wx.lib for the flat look, however there is no way to apply a "theme" to all the widgets in wxPython. Why? Because wxPython tries to wrap the native widgets on each platform, so it does its best to look native. If the native widgets are flat, then you'll see wxPython doing that too. Otherwise, you have to use the custom widgets.

If you want your app to have the "flat" look on all platforms, then you'll probably want to take a look at some other toolkit that allows theming, like Kivy or Tkinter. I think PySide/PyQt might even allow a little theming too.